# How to measure single app CPU usage over time?

Tags: software-recommendation, performance, cpu-load, cpu

I'm doing some performance test for apps in Ubuntu. Is there a nice way (or an application) to measure the CPU usage of a **single app**?

I would be great if it was also possible to create charts of CPU usage over time, but that's not a necessity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using `top | grep <application-name>`, gives you a bunch of stats including CPU usage in percent.

Example: The output while monitoring the application *clementine* using `top`, the column with numbers 8's, 9's and a single 22 and 7 is the line that charts the CPU usage percentage of clementine over a period of time it runs

```
nits@nits-workstation:~$ top | grep clementine
 4729 nits      20   0  408m 101m  23m S    8  5.1   8:59.36 clementine         
 4729 nits      20   0  408m 101m  23m S    8  5.1   8:59.61 clementine         
 4729 nits      20   0  408m 101m  23m S    8  5.1   8:59.86 clementine         
 4729 nits      20   0  408m 101m  23m S    8  5.1   9:00.10 clementine         
 4729 nits      20   0  408m 101m  23m S    9  5.1   9:00.37 clementine         
 4729 nits      20   0  408m 101m  23m S    8  5.1   9:00.62 clementine         
 4729 nits      20   0  408m 101m  23m S    9  5.1   9:00.88 clementine         
 4729 nits      20   0  408m 101m  23m S    9  5.1   9:01.14 clementine         
 4729 nits      20   0  408m 101m  23m S    8  5.1   9:01.39 clementine         
 4729 nits      20   0  408m 101m  23m S    8  5.1   9:01.63 clementine         
 4729 nits      20   0  408m 101m  23m S    8  5.1   9:01.88 clementine         
 4729 nits      20   0  408m 101m  23m S    8  5.1   9:02.11 clementine         
 4729 nits      20   0  408m 101m  23m S    9  5.1   9:02.37 clementine         
 4729 nits      20   0  408m 101m  23m S    8  5.1   9:02.61 clementine         
 4729 nits      20   0  408m 101m  23m S    9  5.1   9:02.89 clementine         
 4729 nits      20   0  408m 101m  23m S   22  5.1   9:03.56 clementine         
 4729 nits      20   0  408m 101m  23m S    9  5.1   9:03.82 clementine         
 4729 nits      20   0  408m 101m  23m S    8  5.1   9:04.07 clementine         
 4729 nits      20   0  408m 101m  23m S    9  5.1   9:04.33 clementine         
 4729 nits      20   0  408m 101m  23m S    9  5.1   9:04.59 clementine         
 4729 nits      20   0  408m 101m  23m S    8  5.1   9:04.83 clementine         
 4729 nits      20   0  408m 101m  23m S    9  5.1   9:05.09 clementine         
 4729 nits      20   0  408m 101m  23m S    8  5.1   9:05.32 clementine         
 4729 nits      20   0  408m 101m  23m S    8  5.1   9:05.56 clementine         
 4729 nits      20   0  408m 101m  23m S    9  5.1   9:05.82 clementine         
 4729 nits      20   0  408m 101m  23m S    8  5.1   9:06.07 clementine         
 4729 nits      20   0  408m 101m  23m S    8  5.1   9:06.32 clementine         
 4729 nits      20   0  408m 101m  23m S    8  5.1   9:06.56 clementine         
 4729 nits      20   0  408m 101m  23m S    9  5.1   9:06.82 clementine         
 4729 nits      20   0  408m 101m  23m S    8  5.1   9:07.07 clementine         
 4729 nits      20   0  408m 101m  23m S    8  5.1   9:07.32 clementine         
 4729 nits      20   0  408m 101m  23m S    7  5.1   9:07.54 clementine         
 4729 nits      20   0  408m 101m  23m S    8  5.1   9:07.79 clementine         
 4729 nits      20   0  408m 101m  23m S    8  5.1   9:08.03 clementine         
 4729 nits      20   0  408m 101m  23m S    8  5.1   9:08.28 clementine         
 4729 nits      20   0  408m 101m  23m S    9  5.1   9:08.54 clementine         
 4729 nits      20   0  408m 101m  23m S    8  5.1   9:08.77 clementine         
 4729 nits      20   0  408m 101m  23m S    9  5.1   9:09.03 clementine         
 4729 nits      20   0  408m 101m  23m S    9  5.1   9:09.29 clementine         
 4729 nits      20   0  408m 101m  23m S    9  5.1   9:09.55 clementine         
 4729 nits      20   0  408m 101m  23m S    8  5.1   9:09.79 clementine         
 4729 nits      20   0  408m 101m  23m S    8  5.1   9:10.03 clementine
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `pidstat` for that. It's in the package `sysstat`.

```
pidstat -p <PID> 1
```

shows CPU utilisation of the given process every `1` second until you cancel it.

`pidstat` can also show lots of other interesting information about a running process, consult the manual page for details.